# How to create shortcut of my project .exe in the same folder were .exe is located?

Tags: c#, path, exe, shortcut

Here is my code:

```
        private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string link = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName + ".lnk";
        var shell = new WshShell();
        var shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(link) as IWshShortcut;
        shortcut.TargetPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
        shortcut.WorkingDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        //shortcut...
        shortcut.Save();
    }
```

This code creates a shortcut on the desktop... I want a shortcut to be created in the same folder where my exe is. I can't point folder path for this because I don't know where other people will unpack it and run it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it does. That's exactly where you said to create it when you used `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`. Why would you expect it to appear somewhere else?

You need to use the same location you're assigning to `shortcut.WorkingDirectory` instead.

```
private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string link = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath +
       System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName + ".lnk";
    var shell = new WshShell();
    var shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(link) as IWshShortcut;
    shortcut.TargetPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
    //shortcut...
    shortcut.Save();
}
```